# Null pointer Exception in progressDialog

Tags: android

When executing async task class for the first time it is executing correctly but while calling it from some other class in progressDialog I am getting Null pointer exception.

Here in progressDialog getting null Pointer exception

```
protected void onPreExecute() {

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Content...");
    pDialog.show();
    pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}
```

Calling from adapterActivity

```
OpenSubContentActivity openSubContentActivity=new OpenSubContentActivity();
openSubContentActivity.new getData().execute();
```

Exception :

```
03-29 21:22:35.398 7641-7641/reva.irving E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-29 21:22:35.398 7641-7641/reva.irving E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-29 21:22:55.353 7641-7641/reva.irving E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: reva.irving, PID: 7641
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:222)
at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:200)
at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:196)
at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:141)
at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
at reva.irving.OpenSubContentActivity$getData.onPreExecute(OpenSubContentActivity.java:98)
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:620)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:567)
at reva.irving.vivcontentAdapter$1.onClick(vivcontentAdapter.java:59)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22462)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6205)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Please help me out with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure you need new an activity by yourself ?

Comment: Activity is same but Calling async task from other activity

Comment: You need to change your architecture: in android, you never say "new MyActivity()". You can start an Activity (if you have an instance of  Context, call startActivity(Intent) on it) and the runtime will instantiate it for you.

Comment: can you make it more clear?